# How do I debug avrdude?

Tags: gpio

As it comes with experimental software more than often, my experiment with avrdude just fails with no explanation:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/wiring-pi $ sudo avrdude -c gpio -p atmega328p

avrdude: AVR device not responding avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I have tried the `-v` switch, but it does not produce any additional useful information. I don't really trust the software - I think it's broken.

I have wired it as follows:

[image: raspberry - atmega wiring]

I have connected atmega 328 to it.

My question is, what can I do to make `avrdude` tell me when it's stuck. Because of the wiring, I can't do anything more to check it.

Comment: I am not an expert on the ATMEGA, but I would be surprised if you can program it without a clock. There seems to be no ceramic resonator etc. There is also a conspicuous lack of bypass capacitors.
You should also tell us how you have connected the devices i.e. what protocol you are trying to use etc - I presume SPI. You can't expect us to trace your wiring and look up the datasheets to see what pins you have used.

Comment: Without a crystal, you might want to tell avrdude to program at a lower speed by adding the `-B10` parameter.